# Azure IOT and Azure Blockchain integration

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-iot-hub

I am looking for a way to integrate the IOT with Blockchain. I need to record the device data (IOT device) into the blockchain. I am successfully able to send data from the device to the IOT Hub.How can I record this data in a block chain created using Azure Ethereum Consortium?

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain and IoT are a marriage made in heaven. Blockchain can enable and augment a variety of application scenarios and usecases for the IoT. No longer are such possibilities too futuristic – as we will discuss in this post.

**IoT Meets Blockchain...**

Blockchain and Internet Of Things (IoT) are easily the two biggest buzzwords in technology at the moment. The IoT encompasses the world of sensors,moving objects like vehicles and really any device that has embedded electronics  to communicate with the outside world – typically over an IP protocol.

**Combine that with Blockchain** – a distributed ledger architecture (DLT) pattern. Combining the two can facilitate the entire lifecycle of IoT devices and applications and prove to be the glue for business processes to act on these events. Consider the following scenario – a private blockchain for a driverless connected car that will enable secure and realtime interactions from the car starting with car startup, driver authentication, smart contracts to exchange insurance and maintenance service information and realtime location info to track safety.

[image: Blockchain and IOT]

You can learn more about IBM BlockChain and develop your own BlockChain @ https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-101-quick-start-guide-for-developers-bluemix-trs/index.html